# SQL Update If exist, Insert if not by checking multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables like these:

1. `files` table

| id | customer | bucket | path | size | createdAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4043973 | 40 | foo | account-40/upload/26f36a10-4aeb-11ed-8a5a-49f4b61eae34_result.png | 2238 | 2022-10-13 11:35:35 |
| 4043972 | 40 | foo | account-40/upload/26e6bfe0-4aeb-11ed-8e31-571f8b74e4db_result.png | 1985 | 2022-10-13 11:35:35 |
| 4043971 | 40 | foo | account-40/upload/26dfe210-4aeb-11ed-8e31-571f8b74e4db_result.png | 1985 | 2022-10-13 11:35:35 |

2. `summary` table

| id | fileId | month | year | downloads |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 585086 | 9 | 2022 | 1 |
| 2 | 584821 | 9 | 2022 | 1 |
| 3 | 584872 | 9 | 2022 | 1 |

There are action logs of the files processed in the system. These logs remain uncategorized. Each uploaded file is added to the `files` table.

Downloads made on the files should be saved to the summary table every day. If the file is processed for the first time in that month, a new row should be added. Operations after the first should increase the `downloads` column by +1.

I can do this with 3 queries. Like this:

Checking whether the file exists:

```sql
SELECT 
    id 
FROM 
    summary
WHERE
    fileId=(SELECT id FROM cloud_storage_files WHERE path=':filePath') AND
    month=:month AND
    year=:year
```

Insert if exists:

```
INSERT INTO 
    summary (fileId, month, year, downloads)
SELECT id, :month, :year, 1 FROM files WHERE path=':filePath'
```

Update if not:

```
UPDATE
    summary,
    files
SET
    summary.downloads = summary.downloads + 1
WHERE
    files.path=':filePath' AND files.id=summary.fileId
```

But since many files are processed daily, there is a lot of data and I want to do all operations in a single sql query.

So far I tried to do it like this:

```sql
IF(SELECT fileId FROM summary 
    WHERE fileId = :fileId
    AND `month` = :month
    AND `year` = :year) 

THEN    
    INSERT INTO 
    summary (fileId, month, year, downloads) VALUES (:fileId, :month, :year, 1)
ELSE
    UPDATE
        summary,
        files
    SET
        summary.downloads = summary.downloads + 1
    WHERE
        files.path='foo-bar-bar' AND files.id=summary.fileId
```

But no dice yet. I would love to hear from anyone who has a solution or suggestion to the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL; what are you *really* using?

Comment: @Larnu It's MySQL wrong tag. Corrected

Comment: UNIQUE index by `(fileId, month, year)` + INSERT .. ODKU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create unique index by file ID and year-month:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx_uni_fileId_month_year
ON summary (fileId, month, year);
```

then insert with duplicate auto-check:

```sql
INSERT INTO summary (fileId, month, year, downloads)
SELECT id, :month, :year, 1 
FROM files 
WHERE path = ':filePath' 
-- or WHERE path IN ( {filepaths list} )
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE downloads = downloads + 1;
```

If a rows with the same `(fileId, month, year)` already exists then it will be updated and downloads amount will be incremented, otherwise new row will be inserted.

Of course, SELECT may return more than one row, and each row will be processed independently.

Comment: Yes! It worked like a charm. I totally forget that I can create unique indexes. Thank you so much